# Show that $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_\beta} = \aleph_\alpha$ when $\aleph_\beta<\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\alpha)$ and some additional conditions are true.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> Show that $\aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_\beta} = \aleph_\alpha$ when
> $\aleph_\beta<\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\alpha)$ and some additional
> conditions are true.

I have been reading the book "Introduction to Set Theory" by Jech and Hrbacek. I have come to an exercise that I have a question about in the chapter on the arithmeric of cardinal numbers in the section on cardinal exponentiation. The exercise statement goes :
$\newcommand{\cf}{\operatorname{cf}}$

> Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal and let $\aleph_{\beta} < \cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$.
> Show that if $\aleph_{\xi}^{\aleph_{\beta}} \leq \aleph_{\alpha}$ for all
> $\xi < \alpha$, then $\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_{\beta}} = \aleph_{\alpha}$.
> [Hint : If $X \subseteq \omega_{\alpha}$ is such that $|X| = \aleph_{\beta}$,
> then $X \subseteq \omega_{\xi}$ for some $\xi < \alpha$.]

My current solution uses the folowing results from the book :

**Theorem 9.3.10 :**
Let us assume the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis. If $\aleph_{\alpha}$ is a singular cardinal, then :
\begin{equation}
\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_{\beta}} = 
 \begin{cases}
 \aleph_{\alpha}  & \text{ if } \aleph_{\beta} < \cf(\aleph_{\alpha})\\
 \aleph_{\alpha + 1}  & \text{ if } \cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \leq \aleph_{\beta} \leq \aleph_{\alpha}\\
 \aleph_{\beta + 1}  & \text{ if } \aleph_{\beta} \geq \aleph_{\alpha}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

**Theorem 9.3.8 :**
Let us assume the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis. If $\aleph_{\alpha}$ is a regular cardinal, then :
\begin{equation}
\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_{\beta}} = 
 \begin{cases}
 \aleph_{\alpha}  & \text{ if } \beta < \alpha \\
 \aleph_{\beta + 1}  & \text{ if } \beta \geq \alpha
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

**Lemma 9.2.8:**
We have for all limit ordinals $\alpha$ :
\begin{equation}
\cf(\alpha) = \alpha \iff \alpha \ \text{is a regular cardinal } 
\end{equation}

**My issue:**
My current proof shows that, whenever $\alpha$ is a limit
cardinal and $\aleph_{\beta} < \cf(\aleph_{\alpha})$, then $\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_{\beta}} = \aleph_{\alpha}$. It does not depend on the entirety of the stated premise being true. This suggests that there is a problem with the solution that I currently have. My solution so far is given below :

If $\aleph_{\alpha}$ is a singular cardinal then by theorem 9.3.10 :
\begin{equation}
\aleph_{\beta} < \cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \Rightarrow \aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_{\beta}} = \aleph_{\alpha} \; \checkmark
\end{equation}
What if $\aleph_{\alpha}$ is regular ? We have by theorem 9.3.8 :
\begin{equation}
\beta < \alpha \Rightarrow \aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_{\beta}} = \aleph_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
So need to prove :
\begin{equation}
\beta < \alpha
\end{equation}
We know by lemma 9.2.8 :
\begin{equation}
\aleph_{\alpha} \text{ is regular } \Rightarrow \cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) = \aleph_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
So :
\begin{equation}
\aleph_{\beta} < \cf(\aleph_{\alpha}) \Rightarrow \aleph_{\beta} < \aleph_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
Where $\aleph_{\alpha}$ is regular. Why can't I just say :
\begin{equation}
\aleph_{\beta} < \aleph_{\alpha} \Rightarrow \beta < \alpha \; \checkmark
\end{equation}
and therefore :
\begin{equation}
\aleph_{\alpha}^{\aleph_{\beta}} = \aleph_{\alpha} \; \checkmark
\end{equation}

Can someone help with this ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using theorems that assume the GCH for a question that doesn't assume the GCH (although the proofs of those theorems might contain some clues). The key is essentially what's in the hint: if $\aleph_\beta<cf(\aleph_\alpha),$ then every function $\omega_\beta\to \omega_\alpha$ is bounded, so $\omega_\alpha^{\omega_\beta}=\bigcup_{\gamma<\alpha}\omega_\gamma^{\omega_\beta}.$

Comment: (And by the way, your reasoning in the attempt is correct... the problem is that you’re using the GCH when you aren’t supposed to be assuming it. The other condition becomes important in the absence of the GCH.)